# is there any way for a route to have multiple urls in Ember.js router?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

like 'match ' in Rails route.

```
 match '/signup',  :to => 'users#new'
```

I Like to clean my URL.

when my user have to signup, I don't like to expose  #/users/new URL, but only /#/signup

Comment: Please explain your reasoning for wanting to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path for the `Users/New` route:

```
this.route('new', { path: '/signup' });
```